# how to show user's “last seen at” time using the seconds received from the server

Tags: javascript, angular, xmpp

i want to display when a user last seen online by time like whatsapp 
using xmpp and angular

i made an xmpp request and i get user last seen by second and i want to convert it to time

what i got :

user last seen 903 seconds ago

what i want :

user last seen at 11:30 pm

Last Activity Response by Server¶

```
 <iq from='juliet@capulet.com'
  id='last1'
  to='romeo@montague.net/orchard'
  type='result'>
 <query xmlns='jabber:iq:last' seconds='903'>Heading Home</query>
 </iq>
```

Comment: use moment.js to format time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take the seconds value you received from server to a variable, you can do it like below.

```
const timeInSeconds = getValueFromServer();
const lastLoggedInTime = new Date(Date.now() - timeInSeconds * 1000);
```

In your html template, you can use `lastLoggedInTime` variable to show the date.